# Getting redundant records

Tags: 7, database

> $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
>
> > ->entityCondition('bundle', 'mypage')
> >     ->fieldCondition('field_mymodule_module','tid', 123,'=')
> >      ->execute();
>
> $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
>
> $or = db_or();
>
> foreach($nids as $nid)
>
> > $or->condition('m.entity_id', $nid, '=');
>
> $query2 = db_select('metatag', 'm')
>
> > ->fields('m', array('entity_id', 'revision_id', 'language', 'data'))
> >     ->condition('m.entity_type', 'node')
> >     ->condition($or)
> >     ->orderBy('entity_id')
> >     ->orderby('revision_id')
> >     ->execute();
>
> while ($record = $query2->fetchAssoc()) {
>
> > ```
> > dpm($record);
> > ```
> >
> > }

As you can see in above code, I'm trying to get metadata information of each node. Getting nids of them turns out to be easy. However, when I use those nids to retrieve metadata, I get so many identical ones. That problem persists even after I removed "or" statement from the db_select and hard-coded entity_id, it returns like 10 identical records. Can anyone shed a light on the problem and where I am doing wrong here?

Comment: $or->condition('m.entity_id', $nids, '='); you are using $nids in this.use $nid in place of $nids

Comment: You are right but as I said in my post, I have dropped the whole "or" statement together and hardcoded the nid but it still returns redundant records. I just tested with db_query and constructed my own SQL statement just to make sure I'm not using db_select wrong, but the problem persists.

Comment: You got all all nodes id in $nids. have you checked that $nids contains unique nodes id

Comment: I did (with devel's dpm), there's only 11 of them and they are all unique.

Comment: This happens because in foreach you are using while loop. and it runs 11 times

Comment: checkout below code.hope it works for you

Comment: I found out why that's happening! It's because each node has multiple revisions so they have different revision_id. That's why I'm getting multiple results for the same node and I can filter that out with DISTINCT. Silly me. Thanks TBI!

Comment: thats good user30646 !

Answer (score 0):

$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')

```
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'mypage')
        ->fieldCondition('field_mymodule_module','tid', 123,'=')
        ->execute();

    $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
    $array=array();

    foreach($nids as $nid)

{
    $query2 = db_select('metatag', 'm')

    ->fields('m', array('entity_id', 'revision_id', 'language', 'data')) ->condition('m.entity_type', 'node')
```

->condition('m.entity_id', $nid, '=')
->orderBy('entity_id') 
->execute()->fetchAssoc();

```
$array[]=$query2 

        }

$array contains all fields value.traverese this array.
Hope this will give you result.
```